# Where is the "labyrinth plate" of a dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

I am trying to diagnose an intermittent error message with a Fisher & Paykel DW920 Dishwasher.

I found the [diagnostics manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/134588472/599090-Diagnostics-920-DW-pdf), and in the section on checking the operation of the wash pump it recommends that I "check labyrinth plate".

> [image: Flow chart]

(Click to enlarge; see box in bottom right corner, second from right.)

I don't know what that is. I have been unable to find a description. The closest I have come is [someone trying to sell me a replacement](https://www.nationwidespares.com.au/521509-labyrinth-plate-dishwasher-fisher-and-paykel).

What is the role of a labyrinth plate, and where can I find it to make sure it is properly serving that role?

Comment: Sounds like a translation oops. Where is that brand from?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_seal

Comment: I found a parts manual for this model [here](https://elektrotanya.com/fisher-paykel_dw820_dw920_parts_list.pdf/download.html#dl) (after running through some CAPCHA, you'll _eventually_ get a download link), and there's nothing in there labeled "labyrinth plate". Maybe take a look, though, to see if something matches the piece in your sales link - it could be a difference in terminology. If that's not it, maybe post a link to the diagnostics manual you're looking at, because I didn't find a reference to "labyrinth plate" in the owner's manual I found.

Comment: Added links. @isherwood: [Fisher & Paykel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_%26_Paykel) is a major brand. It was New Zealand-based and mainly targetting English-speaking countries when this dishwasher was manufactured. (Now it is majority owned by a Chinese manufacturer.)

Comment: @FreeMan: How mysterious! The labyrinth plate for sale is part #521509. The parts manual doesn't have that, but has a part #521506 and #521508, so they clearly are from the same numbering system.

Comment: That diagnostics helps. Have you considered going to the next step (check impellor), just to be sure that's OK? Also, maybe locating the impeller will help locate the labyrinth plate. (Interesting maybe "impellor" is a British spelling while "impeller" is American - my Firefox likes the US version but not the UK version. So there you have it - a comment with acceptable spelling for anywhere in the world. Yes, I know NZ and AU aren't UK, but they were more recently than the US...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part is the PUMP INLET PLATE.  It acts as a filter and has a tortuous path for fluid and can become clogged. It is attached to the Impeller assembly

Comment: Interesting... so the fluid takes a tortuous path through the labyrinthe plate to the pump inlet so that reduced velocity allows suspended solids to drop out... and the solids subsequently clog up the tortuous path.

Comment: errr..  i think we would just call it a filter...